# Use array in Microsoft Access query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a query in Microsoft Access which updates zipcodes/postcodes in a table (`I_Postcodes`) with the `distance` and `time` it takes to travel from a `base` origin zipcode (held in `I_BasePostcode`) to the zipcode concerned.

My `Access` query for determining distance only is:

```
UPDATE I_Postcodes, I_BasePostcode
SET I_Postcodes.DistanceFromBase = GetDistance(I_BasePostcode.Postcode,I_Postcodes.Postcode)
WHERE (I_Postcodes.DistanceFromBase Is Null);
```

The `I_BasePostcode` table looks like:

```
+----------+
| Postcode |
+----------+
| LS1 3EX  |
+----------+
```

and an extract from the `I_Postcodes` table looks like:

```
+----------+------------------+--------------+
| Postcode | DistanceFromBase | TimeFromBase |
+----------+------------------+--------------+
| SW13 9EE |               50 |          200 |
| SW13 9EF |               50 |          201 |
| SW13 9EG |               52 |          210 |
+----------+------------------+--------------+
```

The `GetDistance` function is somewhat complicated for the purposes of this question but it works as I hope and returns an array consisting of two values: A distance integer and a time integer. I can access both by calling:

```
' Distance
GetDistance(Origin, Destination)(0)

' Time
GetDistance(Origin, Destination)(1)
```

I would like to update my query to include the time taken to travel to a destination but am unsure how I can do this without calling the `GetDistance` function twice?

Comment: Is the `GetDistance` function expensive, and is it called frequently for the same values?  If so, it might be worthwhile to build a dictionary of previous calls and the result; this would not only fix your issue of calling the same function twice (you would have two functions that call the same dictionary), but it could potentially speed up duplicate calls for the same from/to locations

Answer (score 1):

Use static variables for returning array and previous argument values in GetDistance function. If arguments are the same and array already has valid values, return array from static variable, otherwise calculate time/distance.

Comment: What would that look like?

Comment: *"Use static variables ..."* - Yup, that's what I had envisioned as well. Another alternative would be to use a Recordset update instead of a SQL query.

Comment: It looks nothing special, just remember that if you use `Static` instead of `Dim` in declarations, the variable keeps current value between function calls, so you don't need to recalculate result if parameters are the same.